# Issue With Subquery Counting Totals

Tags: mysql

I am currently working on a query that will show me a total count of applications that have been received and a count of how many of those applications fit within a particular application status. This will then be grouped by state and client. See below:

```
SELECT STATE AS State1, CLIENT AS Client1, COUNT(DISTINCT ID) AS Count1,
(SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT APPLICATION_ID)
FROM APPLICATION TABLE 1
LEFT JOIN APPLICATION TABLE 2 ON ID1 = ID2
WHERE STATUS = 'APPROVED'
AND DATE_FORMAT(CREATE_DT, '%Y-%m-%d') = '2013-03-28') AS COUNT2
FROM APPLICATION TABLE
JOIN USER TABLE ON USER_ID = ID
LEFT JOIN DECISION TABLE ON DECISITON_ID = ID
WHERE DATE_FORMAT(CREATE_DT, '%Y-%m-%d') = '2013-03-28'
GROUP BY STATE, CLIENT;
```

The output would something like the below:

```
State    Client      App Count     Approved Count
AL       Client 1       2               1
AL       Client 2       4               3
AL       Client 3       10              2
TX       Client 1       9               6 
TX       Client 4       4               3
KS       Client 6       6               4
KS       Client 9       12              10
```

However, I am getting the following:

```
State    Client      App Count     Approved Count
AL       Client 1       2               29
AL       Client 2       4               29
AL       Client 3       10              29
TX       Client 1       9               29
TX       Client 4       4               29
KS       Client 6       6               29
KS       Client 9       12              29
```

What can I do to sum the secondary count of the apps within that particular status correctly?

Comment: If you like, consider following this simple two-step course of action: 1. If you have not already done so, provide proper DDLs (and/or an sqlfiddle) so that we can more easily replicate the problem. 2. If you have not already done so, provide a desired result set that corresponds with the information provided in step 1.

Answer (score 0):

no need for a correlated subquery, you can get the both in the same select statement

```
SELECT STATE AS State1, CLIENT AS Client1, COUNT(DISTINCT ID) AS Count1,
SUM(STATUS = 'APPROVED') as Count2
FROM APPLICATION 
JOIN USER ON USER_ID = ID
LEFT JOIN DECISION  ON DECISITON_ID = ID
WHERE DATE_FORMAT(CREATE_DT, '%Y-%m-%d') = '2013-03-28'
GROUP BY STATE, CLIENT;
```

Answer (score 0):

When you are making your subquery call, you are not correlating with the groupings. So the subquery totals over the entire table (for approved statuses only, of course) and that's why you get the same result on each row. To fix this, you need to include a restriction on state and client in your subquery, like so:

```
SELECT STATE AS State1, CLIENT AS Client1, COUNT(DISTINCT ID) AS Count1,
(SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT APPLICATION_ID)
FROM APPLICATION AS INNER_APPLICATION
LEFT JOIN APPLICATION_2 ON ID1 = ID2
WHERE STATUS = 'APPROVED'
-- these two lines make it work
AND INNER_APPLICATION.STATE = APPLICATION.STATE
AND INNER_APPLICATION.CLIENT = APPLICATION.CLIENT
AND DATE_FORMAT(CREATE_DT, '%Y-%m-%d') = '2013-03-28') AS COUNT2
FROM APPLICATION
JOIN USER TABLE ON USER_ID = ID
LEFT JOIN DECISION TABLE ON DECISITON_ID = ID
WHERE DATE_FORMAT(CREATE_DT, '%Y-%m-%d') = '2013-03-28'
GROUP BY STATE, CLIENT;
```

I had to rename some of your tables because they had spaces in them and it wasn't clear why.

Since you are joining to another table in your subquery, you can't use @radar's answer. However, if the subquery was counting over the same table as your outer query, then you could do that without any problem.